# Actionscript3 Loader error (ERROR #2044, #2032)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to change txt file with AS3 using URLLoader class.
I made a text file "urlLoaderExample.txt" which contains texts like this :

question=age&answer=20

and here's my code :

```
function send_data() : void 
{
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("urlLoaderExample.txt");
    variables.answer = "100";
    variables.question = "salary";
    request.data = variables;

    try 
    { loader.load(request); }  
    catch (error:Error) 
    { trace("Unable to load requested document"); }
}
```

And it makes an error like this...

Error #2044: unhandled ioError text=Error #2032: stream error

am I using this function in a wrong way?

Comment: [look at here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html#includeExamplesSummary) add ProgressEvent, SecurityErrorEvent, IOErrorEvent. I think that you can not edit local files with flash - use AIR. It works if you have file on a server

Comment: See my answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/23301556/1457439

Comment: Also, you should clarify in your question if your app is running on a web server, or on your local system.  Also, make sure your text file is the same directory as your swf.  A try catch on the `loader.load` isn't very helpful, as the the errors are dispatched via asynchronous events.  Again, see the answer in my comment above.

Comment: load text file into AS3 String, use String functions like **indexOf** to find, **replace** to change, **subStr** to extract,  etc etc. When finished editing just save as new file. Is your Flash AIR app (**.exe**?) running on desktop or its a Flash SWF running in web browser? If browser, then use `fileReference.save()` option for a "choose save location" pop up window.

Comment: In case you need **[an example](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3externaltext/)**... so make a `var myString : String = "";` then later inside the load complete event you say `myString = String(e.target.data);` now you a have string to edit with **[String functions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html)**

Comment: You Sure your txt file is put in the right folder?  #2032 seems the target file cannot be found